Why is my UI image pixelated in Unity Game View but not in Scene View?
enter image description here
Problem
I am working on a Unity project and encountering an issue where UI images (both SVG and PNG) appear pixelated in the Game View, regardless of zoom level. However, the same images look perfectly sharp in the Scene View.
My Setup

Canvas Settings:

Canvas Scaler: Scale with Screen Size
Reference Resolution: 3840x2160
Match Width or Height: 0.5


Image Settings:

SVG:

Scale Factor: 100~300


PNG:

Max Size: 2048~16384
Compression: None
Filter Mode: Point(no filter)




Game View:

Resolution: 3840x2160
Scale: 0.22~5.0x


Rendering Pipeline:

Using Universal Render Pipeline with default settings.



Question
Why do UI images appear pixelated in the Game View, even when the resolution is correctly set? How can I make them render as sharply in the Game View as they do in the Scene View?
Adjusted Canvas Scaler settings and Reference Resolution.
Verified import settings for both SVG and PNG files.
Tested with different Game View resolutions and aspect ratios.

Your images appear pixelated because your Game Window scale is set to 2.4x:

To fix this, simply set it to 1x.
And if you want your images to be larger, make them larger by adjusting  Rect Transform instead.

Explanation:
The window to which Unity draws the game has particular size in pixels of the screen. When you zoom in, Unity, well, simply zooms in. Without applying any smoothing, sampling etc. So you can see exactly what is drawn on the screen, just larger.

If, as you say, the image appears pixelated even at 1x scale, you can try the following (and any combination):

Instead of Point, use Bilinear or Trilinear in the Import settings, as Point means no smoothing. This is probably what will fix the issue, but in case this isn't enough, you can also look into the following:
Pixel Perfect in Canvas, if applicable. Read the description carefully, as it isn't a silver bullet: scaled, rotated & animated objects break pixel perfection. And even if done right, it won't fix the pixelation by itself. What it does is it tries to make all the pixels of the image fit into the pixels of the screen, so they don't disappear.
Again, make the image larger. In your screenshot, the image in the Scene View is twice or more larger than the image in the Game View, which is already zoomed 2.4x. The Scene View scaling works differently and doesn't preserve the original pixel resolution, it always draws to the size of screen pixels. So, what you see there is the image drawn with around 5 times more precision. In other words, the image can't be drawn smooth enough if there's not enough pixels to fit it in.


Thank you for the comment. The zoom was just to make it easier to see. The pixelation appears even at 1x or lower scales, and it’s the same after building the project.

@HyeonMin updated the answer. If it is pixelated even at 1x zoom, Point filtering, pixel imperfect positioning and small size of the image are the reason.
